# Generating bar plot of sepearte colours

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a graph like below:

[image]

Code that I have written already is:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
% symbolic x coords={$\tau =5$,$\tau = 10$,$\tau =15$,$\tau =20$, $\tau =25$},
xtick={0.100000, 0.400000, 0.700000, 1.000000},


ylabel={Remaining Energy (Joules)},

xlabel = Time (Megaseconds),
legend style={at={(0.45,1)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5.8pt,]
\addplot[style={fill=blues3,mark=none}] 
coordinates {(0.100000,5586.3) (0.400000,1149)
(0.700000,1089.8)  (1.000000,5112)};\addlegendentry{Lowest Energy}
\addplot[style={fill=blues2,mark=none}]
coordinates {(0.100000, 9543.32) (0.400000, 11607.5)
(0.700000, 10577.22)  (1.000000,13684.17)};\addlegendentry{ Highest Energy}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Energy Status of the WSN at Various Point of Time}

\end{figure}
```

However, this is no way near to the plot that I want. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit unclear. You provide 2 `\addplot` commands each containing 4 `coordinate` pairs, but your sketch contains 4 "`\addplot`s" each containing 2 "`coordinate` pairs". If you could edit your question and be more precise what you really need, we will be happy to help you.